# Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer-Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   guard case let referenceImage == ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "milk", bundle: nil)
   else {
      fatalError("Missing expected catalog resources")
   }
}
```

> Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

keeps popping up at the beginning of the else statement. Do I need to add 'if'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `guard case let referenceImage ...`  with `guard let referenceImage ...`

Also, as mentioned by @koen, change `==` to `=`, so it becomes `guard let referenceImage = ...`

Comment: I replaces guard referenceImage and Use of unresolved identifier 'referenceImage' popped up under referenceImage.

Comment: My bad. I have modified the answer.

Comment: Also change `==` to `=`, so it becomes `guard let referenceImage = ...`.

Comment: So, if I come across Use of unresolved identifier 'referenceImage' again how would you suggest I approach it to fix it?

Comment: Unresolved identifier means the variable, function, class and so on ... is not declared/defined, but is used.